# Is there anyway to deactivate a trigger in Prod when the minumum code coverage is not met

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I am not an apex developer and I am the only SFDC Admin at my company. We are a smaller non-profit org and the directive is to use standard "out of the box" functionality which I can do with my declarative coding knowledge. Probelm, Admins before me created some triggers and did not create enough test classes for them to meet the minimum code coverage of 75%. This means I cannot deploy any changes via Change Sets, I have to do it all manually which is what i have been doing. 
Now we have another trigger created by a previous admin that is causing errors for my users due to a change in Roles/permissions that needed to be implemented. Because I cannot de-activate this trigger (which is not even needed, no one seems to know the reason it was created) users will keep getting the errors and I cannot do any further enhancements needed. I do not know how to create test classes but hope to learn at some point so we can meet code coverage and be able to use the Change Sets but in the meantime I need to get the 1 Trigger causing errors deactivated. Does anyone know of any other tool/app that will allow me to edit the trigger (deactivate) and move it to Prod even though I don't have 75% code coverage?? Salesforce will not help since it's custom code and 
I've exhausted all efforts and knowledge at this point and I'm sure the users as well as my boss will be expecting a resolution. Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably worth noting that they *did* create 75% coverage at some point; they couldn't have deployed any code otherwise, as this requirement has always existed. The usual culprit for low coverage are validation rules added afterwards. Try turning off all your validation rules, then trying to deploy your changes again.

Comment: I don't see how it could have been (which is why I thought you could force changes in via eclipse or something). SFDC support gave me the names of the 4 classes failing code coverage and they are 0% and have not been modified since they were created by the previous admin. 3 out of the 4 appear to be test classes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make any change to code in Production **period**, you must have 75% test coverage.  There are no exceptions for this or tools that will do so.

If the deletion/deactivation of that trigger takes the test coverage over 75%, then that would be acceptable to Salesforce.  Otherwise, your only option is to increase test coverage.  You will need to hire a contractor or figure out how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As @sfdcfox mentioned this is probably Validation written Post Deployment of Trigger. If you are not Sure on Which Object Validations have written, In Inbound change set Try to Validate the Deployment It will Through a many Error like '0 % code coverage..... and 75% code coverage is Required' along with the validation written object.